# Error: use of undeclared identifier on an apparently declared variable

Tags: c, cs50

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    long creditcardno;
    do
    {
        creditcardno = get_long("enter");
    }
    while (creditcardno<1000000000000 || 
           creditcardno > 9999999999999999);

}


int i = 0;
long cc = creditcardno;
while (cc>0);
{
    cc = creditcardno/10;
    i++;
}
```

In the above program in C, I intend to have a variable named cc of long type which will initialize with the value of entered creditcardno by the user.

Getting error message:

*credit.c:14:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'creditcardno'
By "undeclared identifier," clang means you've used a
name creditcardno on line 14 of credit.c which
hasn't been defined. If you mean to use creditcardno as a
variable, make sure to declare it by specifying its type, and
check that the variable name is spelled correctly.*

To my understanding, I have defined variable creditcardno as this variable stores input value of credit card from the user.

Comment: `creditcardno` is local to `main`. Why are you trying to write code outside `main`?

Comment: Note that a semicolon after a `while (...);` is usually wrong; it makes the body of the loop empty, so depending on whether the test is true or false initially, the loop will either do nothing or loop infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write this part of code outside of `main()`. That's why it shows an error.

```
int i = 0;
long cc = creditcardno;
while (cc>0);
{
    cc = creditcardno/10;
    i++;
}
```

`creditcardno` is a variable inside the main scope. That's why it is only accessible from the main scope.